# set maximum heap size for maven

Tags: maven, jvm, maven-3, heap-memory

I am using MacBook Pro with **OSX Yosemite**. When I run `maven clean install` under my java project, I constantly get error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I googled a bit, and followed a suggestion to add environment variable to set bigger heap size for maven.

I edited **~/.bash_profile** , added the following line:

```
setenv MAVEN_OPTS "-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

and run `maven clean install` again, But still I got `OutOfMemoryError`. How could I set my maven to use maximum 1024M heap?

**=== UPDATE ====**

The full log :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex$ZipDirectory.findCENRecord(ZipFileIndex.java:552)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex$ZipDirectory.<init>(ZipFileIndex.java:497)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex.checkIndex(ZipFileIndex.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex.<init>(ZipFileIndex.java:137)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndexCache.getZipFileIndex(ZipFileIndexCache.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.openArchive(JavacFileManager.java:559)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.openArchive(JavacFileManager.java:482)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.listContainer(JavacFileManager.java:368)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:644)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:2446)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:2143)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:421)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:298)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:459)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:258)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:272)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:484)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:929)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:823)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough this is a very old thread, I think it is worth adding that the following configuration can be used when using the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <configuration>
          <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in tests run by surefire plugin. You should include opts in `<argLine>` in surefire `<configuration>` tag instead of MAVEN_OPTS:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I am using surefire plugin

Comment: Could you share wider log output? Do you have any tests in your application?

Comment: @ Jakub Kubrynski, the full log is added. Please check my update.

Comment: Could you check using jmap -heap <MAVEN_PID> what is your heap setting?

Comment: I am not able to get maven heap size by your suggested command. But I checked my java heap size, InitialHeapSize = 6815736, MaxHeapSize=35651584, PermSize=21757952, MaxPermSize=85983232